# AVAudioRecorder will not record in special cases

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to use AVAudioRecorder to record the users voice.When I use this code it works:

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd ss"];
NSString *dateWithString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateWithString);
NSString *soundFilePath1 = [docsDir
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:nil];
NSString *soundFilePath = [soundFilePath1
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

NSLog(@"%@",soundFilePath);

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error2;

self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error2];
```

However it does not work when I use:

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd ss"];
NSString *dateWithString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateWithString);
NSString *soundFilePath1 = [docsDir
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:dateWithString];
NSString *soundFilePath = [soundFilePath1
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

NSLog(@"%@",soundFilePath);

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error2;



self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error2];
```

---

The difference between these two blocks of code is:

```
NSString *soundFilePath1 = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dateWithString];
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check your directory is created properly or not.

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd ss"];
    NSString *dateWithString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateWithString);
    docsDir = [[dirPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dateWithString];

    NSError *e;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:docsDir])    //Does directory already exist?
    {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:docsDir
                                       withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                        attributes:nil
                                                             error:&e])
        {
            NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", e);
        }
    }
```

After that apply,

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

    NSLog(@"%@",soundFilePath);



    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath isDirectory:NO];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(IBAction)record:(id)sender
{
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSDate  *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd ss"];
NSString *dateWithString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@",dateWithString);

NSString *dateFolderPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:dateWithString];
NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dateFolderPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dateFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

NSString *soundFilePath = [dateFolderPath
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

NSLog(@"%@",soundFilePath);

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error2;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
            initWithURL:soundFileURL
            settings:recordSettings
            error:&error2];
[recorder record];
}

-(IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
  [recorder stop];
  NSLog(@"stop");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioRecorder records audio in top level in document directory or in temporary directory. If you try to record audio at folder created in document directory, then it will fail. Always record audio in temporary directory and after recording move file to your folder in Document directory.